# Add javascript-config-file to herokuapp?

Tags: git, heroku

I have two versions of a codebase. One on heroku and one on another server. Each has a javascript-file that contains a bunch of settings that are specific for that server. I mostly pull down changes from the non heroku-server and the push them to heroku when I do updates. Is there a way to not overwrite the config-file on Heroku when I do this?

I know about confg Vars, but it's not very suitable, as I don't run any backend stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing a repo where I locked the config file and just added the files to that repo manually. NOt the neatest solution perhaps, but it works really well.